# ScrollBar on Top of Html Content

Tags: html, css

as you know if html content vertical view is more than browser window, a vertical scroll bar will add to page. It will cause moving html content into left which does not have a good view.

You can avoid this treat using this CSS code:

```
html{
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

But there is a problem with this code, you will always see a disabled scroll bar on right side of the page. Now let's check another way, in this way you will subtract body width of the scroll width:

```
    body {
        width: calc(100vw - 68px);
        margin-left: 34px;
    }
```

This will put body in center and if in future a vertical scroll bar add to the page, it won't affect content and will be on the right side out of the body area! This way is good but there is a very little problem. you have subtracted your body width!!! Just think I have a fully filled body area! In this situation I need the whole 100% width and also I do not want the scroll bar to move my content into left and also I do not want to see a disabled scroll bar always!

So I'm looking for a way I can make scroll bar while showing on top of html content. so Nothing will move and also I have 100% width and when ever it is needed I will see scroll bar.

Is there such trick? Hope I'm clear enough.

Comment: It would be easier to answer if your question had screenshots. Styling scrollbars in a cross-browser way is impossible. You should use some JS library which creates scrollbars.

Comment: If you're asking what I think you're asking, you want to hide the rightmost part of the body content behind the scrollbar, [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/j4fc37w3/1/), is that right?

Comment: Yes Exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Stranger Why? It looks horrible.

Comment: Why Horrible? Just think a little part of background will hide. It won't affect My page's design Of Course ;)

Comment: My example hides just a little part of the text.